# Can bitbake run two tasks from the same recipe at the same time?

Tags: yocto, bamboo, bitbake, openembedded

I am currently trying to run a Yocto build in my CI/CD infrastructure (Bamboo) and my build is failing without any useful information. I have been struggling to debug this in the past few days.

I am running the job inside a container that is running on a virtual machine.
The virtual machine has an octa-core processor and 24Gb of memory.

The bitbake command just get aborted without printing any error and the build task fails:

```
19-Apr-2023 04:55:19    NOTE: Running task 11785 of 11810 (/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MAS-MASPR5-BS2/poky/../meta-browser/meta-chromium/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium-ozone-wayland_111.0.5563.64.bb:do_package)
19-Apr-2023 04:55:19    NOTE: Running task 11786 of 11810 (/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MAS-MASPR5-BS2/poky/../meta-browser/meta-chromium/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium-ozone-wayland_111.0.5563.64.bb:do_populate_sysroot)
19-Apr-2023 04:55:19    NOTE: recipe chromium-ozone-wayland-111.0.5563.64-r0: task do_package: Started
19-Apr-2023 04:55:20    NOTE: recipe chromium-ozone-wayland-111.0.5563.64-r0: task do_populate_sysroot: Started
19-Apr-2023 04:55:24    Failing task since return code of [/tmp/runInDocker694722963655912624.sh /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/MAS-MASPR5-BS2-4-ScriptBuildTask-4563655698926000920.sh] was 137 while expected 0
```

I noticed that the task do_populate_sysroot is started before the task do_package finishes. Can bitbake run two tasks for the same recipe at the same time? Is this a normal bitbake/yocto behavior or is it just a symptom of another error? I have never got this error on my development machine.

**What do I expect?**

I would expect to finish the task without an 137 error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bitbake will happily run multiple tasks in the same recipe in parallel.

Exit code 137 means you've ran out of memory. Chromium is notoriously memory hungry to build, especially if you've multiple build threads in parallel.

Either allocate the VM more ram, or reduce the parallelisation of that recipe (eg `PARALLEL_MAKE:pn-chromium-ozone-wayland="-j4"` in your config).